# What could be the reason for the large difference between sodium and potassium blood concentrations?

Tags: physiology, hematology

Reference values for sodium and potassium concentrations in blood tests are usually in the range of 135-145 mEq/L and 3.5-5.1 mEq/L, respectively.

My question is what could be the reason for this (relatively) large difference in the blood concentrations of these two ions which are together responsible for cells function and communication? What other roles does sodium play outside of cells that require it to be **a lot more** abundant in the blood than potassium?

Also, a follow-up question: is this proportion more-or-less maintained in other animal species?

Comment: This is much too broad. Some reading on your part about [homeostasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeostasis) is in order. If you still have a question then, and can explain why it is unclear from your reading, that would be a narrower question. The short answer is because it's necessary for life. When we die, equilibration occurs (more or less).

Comment: Although this is a fairly broad question, I think it could still be given an appropriately-scoped answer. One bit of information missing from the question that would make it more interesting is the imbalance between extra- and intra-cellular concentrations: not just that Na+ concentrations are greater than K+ in the blood but that the opposite is true in a typical cell.

Comment: @anongoodnurse, I have studied some basic physiology, including nervous system physiology, and I am aware of electrical activity in the cell, membrane potential, ion pumps etc. This question focuses on a very narrow (in my opinion) aspect of this very broad subject, which is merely **the quantities**. Actually, it came up when I was reviewing a patient's blood tests - I looked at the normal ranges and asked myself: "how come sodium blood concentration is 30-40 times greater than potassium?", or in other words, why did evolution settle on this proportion? Perhaps no one knows, but worth a try.

Comment: @Don_S - Sorry, the question read like a beginner's. In that case, God only knows, but it is still too broad. (I was a Molecular Biologist before I became a physician.)

Comment: Wait, here's an idea: nothing else lived long enough to reproduce. That answer is probably as accurate as any.

Comment: Well, thanks for sharing your thoughts. For me, this is the place to come before giving up... I hope the question won't be closed, at least 3 people liked it...

Comment: Sorry that this is an extremely simplified answer, but basically, cells make use of the concentration *gradients* (and some cells the electrical gradients) produced by pumping sodium out of cells and pumping potassium in. A lot of that functionality would be achieved by simply pumping sodium out, but something has to go in its place or else you would have osmotic effects. The "choice" of sodium/potassium is reasonable because those ions are freely available where life evolved, but are probably still used because a shift would be an enormous challenge to overcome.

Comment: I hope someone will come along with an actual full answer but in the meantime I just hope the question isn't closed, I think it's a good one for people at many levels of understanding. As far as other animal species, to my knowledge yes the general pattern is maintained. It likely originates from "extracellular" ion concentrations being seawater, so it is very old.